# YouTube API .NET C# editing video problem

Tags: .net, api, video, youtube, edit

I use the newest YouTube API to upload movies by my users. Upload works but I have problem with editting properties after that. I'm trying like this:

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("NETUnittests", YTDeveloperKey, YTUser, YTPassword);

settings.Timeout = 10000000;
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Google.YouTube.Video video = new Google.YouTube.Video();
//video.VideoId = lblVideoID.Text;

//http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USER_ID/uploads/VIDEO_ID

Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + lblVideoID.Text);
video = request.Retrieve<Google.YouTube.Video>(videoEntryUrl);

if (video.ReadOnly == false)
{

}

string tt = video.Title;
string dd = video.Description;

video.Title = tbTitle.Text;
video.Description = tbDescription.Text;
video.Keywords = tbKeywords.Text;

//video.Status.Value = "private";
request.Update(video);
```

First of all video.ReadOnly = true so I the object is uneditable. When I'm trying to perform request.Update(video); I get an error that Object is not found - sth like that. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the URL

```
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + lblVideoID.Text);
```

I have fixed the issue by changing the URL to

```
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/" + lblVideoID.Text);
```

Try it and it will work fine.