# youtube api updating video information using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api

I am using the Youtube api for asp.net to rename a video:

```
    public static void UpdateVideoInfo(string video_id, string new_title) 
    {
        Uri entry = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + video_id);
        Video video = AuthRequest().Retrieve<Video>(entry);

        if (video.ReadOnly == false)
        {
            video.Title = new_title;
        }
        else video.Title = video.Title;

        Video updatedvideo = AuthRequest().Update(video);
    }
```

but i get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

***on the last line.***

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be is the same problem reported here, with a different error message..

[YouTube API .NET C# editing video problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943287/youtube-api-net-c-sharp-editing-video-problem)

Comment: Wired that the same URI will work for retrieving the video but not updating it. Anyway Thank you Matias. works fine.